# Time Failure Issue - Katalon

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I found on the internet a solution for Time failure issue(Without adding any random delay), but anytime I add it to my code got an error.

Here is the error:

Test Cases/Logging into account/Logging in - Right details FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: G_Timeout_Small for class: internal.GlobalVariable
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1004)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1859)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1835)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3735)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
    at Script1543314158625.run(Script1543314158625.groovy:39)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:183)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:108)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:294)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:264)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:256)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:200)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:99)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:90)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at TempTestCase1543410680790.run(TempTestCase1543410680790.groovy:22)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:507)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:653)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:384)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:370)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:129)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
)

Test Cases/Logging into account/Logging in - Right details.run:39

Here is my code:

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable

'Opening the browser.'
WebUI.openBrowser('')

'Importing account details from file.'
def plik = new File('Config.txt')

'Importing account details from file.'
def lines = plik.readLines()

WebUI.waitForPageLoad(0)

'Loading the page.'
WebUI.navigateToUrl(lines[0])

'Typing the account name.\n'
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Logging into the account/account area'), lines[1])

'Typing the password'
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Logging into the account/password area'), lines[2])

'Logging into the website with the logging button'
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Logging into the account/log button'), FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)

WebUI.waitForPageLoad(GlobalVariable.G_Timeout_Small)

'Verifying wether logged or not.'
WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Logging into the account/main div after being logged'), 0)

'Closing the browser.'
WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

and place where I found it:
https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/solving_common_issue_wait_time.html

Anyone has any idea why there is that error ? In advance "Yes there is importe library for Global Variable.

Comment: What is `GlobalVariable.G_Timeout_Small` set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set initial value for `GlobalVariable.G_Timeout_Small`.

Go to execution profiles ("Profiles" at the top of the "Tests Explorer" on the right side of Katalon Sudio window) and set `G_Timeout_Small` to initial (number) value.

[image: Example screenshot:]

Comment: Done the job didn't know I have to set anything there